# binding.pry で、 expression からメソッドを呼び出しながらそこに step できるか。

Tags: ruby, pry

binding.pry を使っていると、 binding でプログラムが一時停止して pry が起動しているときに、「このオブジェクトのこのメソッドを呼び出して、中がどうなっているのか確認したい、ソースコード上はそんなメソッドコールはなされないんだけれども」

という場合が発生します。

質問:

- binding.pry で一時停止・起動した pry の上で、ruby 式の評価ができますが、その今 REPL に入力している式に対して step したくなりました。これを行う方法はありますか？
- 今だと、その呼び出したいメソッドコールを、対象ソースコードの binding.pry する直後に挿入して、一時停止した直後に step して中を見ているのですが、ソースコードをわざわざ変更しなくてもできた方が、よりやりやすいので、これができないかと思い、質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747003/debug-into-method-from-production-irb

がどうやら利用できそうです。単純に pry の上で:

```
[1] pry(#<SomeClass>)> binding.pry; obj.method(*args) # 普通にメソッドを呼ぶ。
```

するとそのメソッドへ step できました。